# How to do in Argo Events : Passing Kafka event-source messages listens on kafka topics and sends back the message to the event-hub sensor trigger

Tags: argocd, argo-workflows, argo, argo-events

The structure of an event dispatched from kafka broker

```
{
  "id" : "12hhj-udhahj12-bsjdjs93",
  "name" : "test"
}
```

How to add the dispacted data from kafka event-source into event-hub sensor payload alogn with few additional json attribute.

the expected structure of event-hub sensor payload for trigger will be

```
 {
"email": "test@abc.com",
"org": "xxx",
"data": {
    "id": "12hhj-udhahj12-bsjdjs93",
    "name": "test"
}
}
```

referenced docs:
https://argoproj.github.io/argo-events/eventsources/setup/kafka/

https://argoproj.github.io/argo-events/sensors/triggers/azure-event-hubs/

I did the setup for both kafka event-source and event-hub sensor, by setting some dummy data in event-hub sensor payload consfiguration the work flow works. my expectation will be how to fetch the data sent from kafka event-source and send back to event-hub sensor trigger by setting in the payload or some other way.